# How might my browser session be hijacked on iOS Safari?

Tags: web-browser, safari

I'm currently on iOS using Safari, and my browser session was just hijacked. Ive never seen any hint of malware on iOS, so I'm going to assume the hijacking occured (consistently happens when visiting Rotten Tomatoes, and no other site) via the web page. Is it likely that such a monster site could be hacked? Maybe I'm wrong and its an iOS security issue?

I visit Rotten Tomatoes, scroll (no links clicked) and my page location changes but sometimes *before* the content of RT dissapears, I get a browser alert popup. The URL has changed, but the Fandango website hasnt yet dissapeared - this in itself seems like a security issue.

Can anyone explain where the security failure could be? Is my device compromised (It's never been jailbroken or unlocked)? Is this a browser security failure? A W3C issue? Rotten Tomatoes hacked?

I'd just like to figure out what aspect of security on my phone has a jole it in. Once I visit Rotten Tomatoes on the phone, the scam page traps me. The only way to get out is to close the tab, otherwise popups continue to appear.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a rather insidious ad which Rotten Tomatoes happens to have on their site. I've seen several other sites where they redirect me to a URL which then opens the App Store and I can't get back to the original site... Because of the sand boxing of iOS apps and because you have not jail broken your device, I have no reason to suspect malware in your device.